# detecting devices connected to my network

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming

I need Java code to detect current connected devices to my network.
I tried the following idea :
 - for all possible addresses check if this address is connected ( 254 loop ) 
 - to speed up this process I created a thread for each check to make them run in parallel

Is there any way more efficient ??

Comment: http://www.rootsecure.net/content/downloads/pdf/nmap_host_discovery.pdf describes the techniques used by nmap.  Even if you don't find a way that suits you, you won't regret reading this document.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are lots of ways of detecting networked devices and you give no specifics on the nature of your situation.

The simplest (and most simplistic) approach I can think of would be to ping the broadcast address of your IP network and then consult the system's ARP table.
Unfortunately I have no particular strategy for accessing the ARP table from Java to suggest.

Comment: what's meant by the ARP table ?

Comment: Ask the all-knowing Google: "ARP table" produces these two links at the top: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol , http://www.tildefrugal.net/tech/arp.php